# Missing zero when trying to get \value of counter

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I'm using the below code to try and define a new list which displays like the below picture. when I try and get the \value of mrcenumi to add one to it, I get a missing number, treated as zero error. Any advice on why this is happening?

```
 \usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{mrcenumi}
\setcounter{mrcenumi}{1}%
\newcounter{mrcenumii}
\setcounter{mrcenumii}{1}%

\newlist{mrcenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[mrcenum,1]{label=\themrcenumi.}
\setlist[mrcenum,2]{label=\the\numexpr(\value{mrcenumi} + 1) \relax}
\setlist[mrcenum,3]{label*=\arabic*.}
```

[image: m]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\protect\the`, because of how `enumitem` sets the `label` at `\setlist`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mrcenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[mrcenum,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[mrcenum,2]{label=\protect\the\numexpr\value{mrcenumi}+1\relax.\arabic*.}
\setlist[mrcenum,3]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{mrcenum}
\item a
\item b
  \begin{mrcenum}
  \item c
  \item d
    \begin{mrcenum}
    \item e
    \item f
    \end{mrcenum}
  \item g
  \end{mrcenum}
\item h
\end{mrcenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. Works perfectly now